Error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
I'm working on a Maven multi-module project and encountered an issue with Spring Boot. My project structure includes Common, Parent, Management, and Client modules. Specifically, I'm having trouble with the User entity not being recognized as a managed type by Hibernate. The error I'm seeing is:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/path/to/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/path/to/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.gigantic.admin.Repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.gigantic.entity.User

My project structure looks like this:
com.gigantic
├── Gigantic-Common
│   └── src/main/java/com/gigantic/entity
│       └── User.java
├── Gigantic-Web-Parent
│   └── pom.xml
├── Gigantic-management
│   └── src/main/java/com/gigantic/admin
│       ├── Controller
│       │   └── UserController.java
│       ├── Service
│       │   └── UserService.java
│       └── Repository
│           └── UserRepository.java
│   └── src/main/java/com/gigantic/management
│       └── Application.java
├── client
│   └── ...

The User entity is located in the common module:
package com.gigantic.entity; import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.Id; @Entity public class User { @Id private Long id; private String username; private String password; // Getters and setters }

My main application class in the management module is set up to scan for entities, repositories, and components:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends IdBasedEntity {

    //Attributes

    @Column(length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
......

The UserRepository is defined as follows:
package com.gigantic.admin.Repository;

import com.gigantic.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
....

The UserService is defined as follows:
@Service
@Transactional
@Component
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
.....

The UserController is defined as follows:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final  RoleService roleService;

    public UserController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roleService = roleService;
  .....

In my pom.xml for the management module, I have added the dependency to the common module:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gigantic</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies like Spring Boot, JPA, etc. -->
</dependencies>

Despite setting up the project this way, I am still encountering the error that User is not a managed type. I have verified that the User entity is annotated with @Entity and that the package scanning configuration includes the com.gigantic.entity package. I have also ensured that the management module depends on the common module in the pom.xml.
My Repo Link : https://github.com/6531503042/Gigantic-Mall
What could be causing Hibernate to not recognize the User entity as a managed type? How can I resolve this issue?
